# Accessor Method to view private variable based on argument in a class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, methods, private, accessor

My problem is that I have many variables in my class and I want them to be accessed via an accessor method. Of course I could have several accessor functions to output my private variables but how can I make it so I can access any of them via an argument. My class:

```
class Character {
public:
    void setAttr(string Sname,int Shealth,int SattackLevel,int SdefenseLevel)  {
        name = Sname;
        health = Shealth;
        attackLevel = SattackLevel;
        defenseLevel = SdefenseLevel;

    }
    int outputInt(string whatToOutput)  {
        return whatToOutput //I want this to either be health, attackLevel or defenseLevel
    }

private:
    string name;
    int health;
    int attackLevel;
    int defenseLevel;
};
```

Basically what I want to know is how do I return a private variable in regards to the outputInt function. Most OOP tutorials have one function to return each variable which seems like a very unhealthy thing to do in a large program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't support what you try to accomplish: reflection or detailed runtime information about objects. There is something called "Run-Time Type Information" in C++, but it can't provide information about your variable name: the reason is because, in the compiled and linked binary this information (names of your variables) will not be necessarily present anymore.

However, you can accomplish something close to that, using i.e. [std::unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) instead of plain integer variables. So it's possible to access values by their names, as strings.
Please consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Character {
public:
  void setAttr(const string& Sname, int Shealth, int SattackLevel, int SdefenseLevel) {
    name = Sname;
    values.insert(std::make_pair("health", Shealth));
    values.insert(std::make_pair("attackLevel", SattackLevel));
    values.insert(std::make_pair("defenseLevel", SdefenseLevel));
  }
  int outputInt(const string& whatToOutput) {
    return values.at(whatToOutput);
  }

private:
  string name;
  std::unordered_map<std::string, int> values;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Character yourCharacter;
  yourCharacter.setAttr("yourName", 10, 100, 1000);
  std::cout << "Health: " << yourCharacter.outputInt("health") <<std::endl;
  std::cout << "Attack level: " << yourCharacter.outputInt("attackLevel") << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Defense level: " << yourCharacter.outputInt("defenseLevel") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It will output as expected:

```
Health: 10
Attack level: 100
Defense level: 1000
```

Another option without dependency on `unordered_map` would be, to use predefined static strings for your variable names and an array or vector for your values. So we could replace the `class Character` above with something like:

```
static std::string variableNames[3] = {
  "health",
  "attackLevel",
  "defenseLevel"
};

class Character {
public:
  void setAttr(const string& Sname, int Shealth, int SattackLevel, int SdefenseLevel) {
    name = Sname;
    variableValues[0] = Shealth;
    variableValues[1] = SattackLevel;
    variableValues[2] = SdefenseLevel;
  }
  int outputInt(const string& whatToOutput) {
    int retVal = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(variableNames)/sizeof(std::string); ++i) {
      if (!whatToOutput.compare(variableNames[i])) {
        retVal = variableValues[i];
      }
    }
    return retVal;
  }

private:
  string name;
  int variableValues[3];
};
```

And getting still same output. However, here you have to manage a list with all your variable names inside the string array manually - I don't like this solution and would prefer one of the others above personally.

Most common ways in C++ to handle such a design is to have seperate `getHealth()`, `getAttackLevel()`, `getDefenseLevel()` functions instead. However, this will miss one use-case, which is: if you want to let the user input a string, like i.e. `"health"` and display the corresponding variable then, you would need to write code by yourself to call the corresponding `getXXX()` function. If this is not a issue in your case, consider the following code which is much cleaner:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Character {
public:
  void setAttr(const string& Sname, int Shealth, int SattackLevel, int SdefenseLevel) {
    name = Sname;
    health = Shealth;
    attackLevel = SattackLevel;
    defenseLevel = SdefenseLevel;
  }
  int getHealth() const { return health; }
  int getAttackLevel() const { return attackLevel; }
  int getDefenseLevel() const { return defenseLevel; }
private:
  string name;
  int health, attackLevel, defenseLevel;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Character yourCharacter;
  yourCharacter.setAttr("yourName", 10, 100, 1000);
  std::cout << "Health: " << yourCharacter.getHealth() <<std::endl;
  std::cout << "Attack level: " << yourCharacter.getAttackLevel() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Defense level: " << yourCharacter.getDefenseLevel() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

One other unrelated advice: Instead of using string as parameter types for your functions, use `const string&` (const reference to string; see my example code above). This allows easier calling of your functions (they can be called directly with an string literal without the need to create additional variables in the calling code) and they will not make a additional unnecessary copy. The only copy then will take place at: `name = Sname;` (in your code two copies took place).

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I know I could have used the below code to output but I was thinking if I had a really big class with loads of variables which may need returning that this would would take a long time coding. I understand the second block of code but for the first block of code, is values basically like an associative array?
edit: I learned about pointers& references today and they are confusing me. The only thing I understand is that a reference can be used in a function so it manipulates the main variable as well as the alias (which is what you have done) why would you use pointers?

Comment: I have tried the below code and worked like a charm but I can't seem to get the name to work!!. In my header file I declare the function:  string getName() const; and in my Character.cpp I make the method: Character::getName  { return newName; }. This is just like all the other int methods. Do you have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: @mre12345 In your Character.cpp you should write `string Character::getName const{ return newName; }` - I think you missed the `const` there. If this is not solving your problem, please write the exact error message compiler is giving.

Comment: Sorry if this is really late as I haven't been able to access the computer but  I think the getName function thinks that I want to return an int even though i have set the function to return a string!!'. He is a printscreen on my error:
http://prntscr.com/8pddt8
EDIT: If i make the whole function in the Character.h, it will work but I have heard this is bad practise.

Comment: @mre12345 You're missing the return value `string` in your screenshot. it should be: `string Character::getName const{ return newName; }`, not just `Character::getName const{ return newName; }` (otherwise compiler assumes wrongly it's `int`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be a good idea for you, but you can use a public typedef struct that you pass by reference and set your value.

```
class Character {
public:
    //...
    typedef struct allvalues{
        string vname;
        int vhealth;
        int vattackLevel;
        int vdefenseLevel;
    }allvalues;

    void getValues(allvalues& val){
        val.vname = name;
        val.vhealth = health;
        val.vattackLevel = attackLevel;
        val.vdefenseLevel = detenseLevel;
    }

    //...
};

//...
//somewhere in the code
Character myCarac;


//...
//Here how to use it
Character::allvalues values;
myCarac.getValues(values);
```